# How to make this rust code compile successfully

Tags: rust

I wrote this code.

```
struct S<'a> {
    pub a: i32,
    pub b: &'a i32,
    pub c: i32,
}
impl<'a> S<'a> {
    fn g(&'a mut self) {
        f(self);
        // self.b=&self.c;
        self.a += 1;
    }
}
fn f<'a>(a: &'a mut S<'a>) {
    a.b = &a.c;
}
```

But I got "cannot use `self.a` because it was mutably borrowed
use of borrowed `*self`"
How do I modify the function f to make it work?

I tried to replace the function call with annotated code, and it worked.

Comment: There's a duplicate somewhere that gives more details, but in short: `&'a mut S<'a>` is _always_ wrong. You want to use two lifetimes here: `&'b mut S<'a>`